# Why the RxJS finalize() arrow functions code seems to be not executed in this code that upload files on Firebase Storage?

Tags: javascript, angular, firebase, rxjs, firebase-storage

I am working on an Angular application and I am creating a service method that have to store multiple files into Firebase Storage and I have the following problem\doubt.

This is my service method code:

```
async uploadFileIntoFirebaseStore(filesList: any[]) {
  const that = this;


  console.log("FILES TO BE SAVED: ", filesList);

  filesList.forEach(function (item, index) {
    console.log(item.name, index);
  
    // The storage path
    const path = `test/${Date.now()}_${item.name}`;

    // Reference to storage bucket
    const ref = that.storage.ref(path);

    // The main task
    that.task = that.storage.upload(path, item);

    // Progress monitoring
    that.percentage$ = that.task.percentageChanges();

    that.snapshot$ = that.task.snapshotChanges().pipe(
      tap(console.log),
      // The file's download URL
      finalize( async() =>  {
        that.downloadURL = await ref.getDownloadURL().toPromise();
        console.log("FILE NAME: ", item.name + " URL: ", that.downloadURL);  
      }),
    );
  });
}
```

As you can see it takes an array containing the files list that have to be saved into Firebase Storage.

I am iterating on this list creating an unique name for each file (so when it is saved on Firebase Storage I avoid collisions), then I retrieve the storage reference and I create the storage upload task.

And here the first doubt: if I am uploading n files have I to create n **task** objects ore can I use a single task object to store n files?

The task correctly save my file into Firebase Storage by this line:

```
that.task = that.storage.upload(path, item);
```

Files are correctly saved on the Firebase Storage.

Then I am using the **snapshotChanges()** in order to obtain the **snapshot$** Observable object and into the arrow function and into the **finalize()** arrrow function I defined the behavior to retrieve the URL of the uploaded file in order to print it into the console.

The problem is that I don't obtain this information into my Chrome console.

This is the output in my console:

```
asset.service.ts:62 FILES TO BE SAVED:  [File]
asset.service.ts:65 Schermata da 2020-11-26 21-26-23.png 0
```

that referers to these console line:

```
console.log("FILES TO BE SAVED: ", filesList);
```

and this one into my foreach loop:

```
console.log(item.name, index);
```

but I have nothing related to this one defined into the finalize() arrow function:

```
console.log("FILE NAME: ", item.name + " URL: ", that.downloadURL);
```

If I use the debugger putting a breack point into the first line of the first line of the finalize() arrow function, this one:

```
that.downloadURL = await ref.getDownloadURL().toPromise();
```

it seems that is never executed.

Why? What is wrong? What am I missing? How can I fix this issue?

Comment: `finalize` is only reached when the observable _completes_; there could be more changes in the future, so presumably that observable never does.

Comment: @jonrsharpe ehhh I know but why? in theory it have to be executed when it completes and the file is saved on Firebase Storage but it seems not work

Comment: What do you mean *"in theory"* - according to what? Do the docs say it completes, for example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on what I read about the firestore my guess is that the `finalize()` is not executed because the `snapshotChanges` Observable does not complete. You can maybe rewrite your code to wait for `n` emissions instead (`takeUntil`) or maybe have the `await ref.getDownloadURL().toPromise()` be the condition on which you can have your file upload be `completed`